# Generate .so file in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, android-ndk

I'm aware that there are answers related to this, but they're old and outdated. I got Android Studio 1.3 and already downloaded Android NDK. When I run an app, it crashes and gives `findLibrary returned null` in `Logcat`. I figured out this was due to no `.so` library file (Correct me if I'm wrong). My question is - **How do I generate a .so file in Android Studio?**

**What I have -**

- Android Studio 1.3 Stable version
- Gradle 1.5
- Android Experimental Plugin 0.2

**Notice -** If the library `.so` file has to be built from `Cygwin` or `CMD`, please tell me how to do it.

Comment: were you able to generate .so file using studio 2.1 ?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

There are a few steps needed to get the NDK hooked up into Android Studio. Currently, support is marked as *experimental* and AS is starting to bundle the ability to download the NDK within the IDE. By default, AS uses a generic `Android.mk` and `Application.mk` when source and/or libs are placed in the `jni` or `jniLibs` folder. The instructions below override those defaults in order to provide more customization ability.

In short, you will need to:

1. Create the default `jni` and `jniLibs` directories for your source and libs.
2. Tell Android Studio where to find your NDK build chain
3. Tell gradle how to compile and where to place your libs
4. Create an `Android.mk` file to specify building and linking order
5. Create some source

---

**Create directories**

Inside `/app/src/main` create a `jni` and `jniLibs` directory.

**Update local.properties**

Inside your `local.properties` file, add a line similar to:

`ndk.dir=/home/nathan/development/bin/android-ndk-r10e`

**Update build.gradle**

This refers to the module level, not the application level. This ensures that we have defined the build path in the step above and removes the ability for Android Studio to automatically invoke ndk-build. Use the following example as a guide.

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
android {
    compileSdkVersion = 23
    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.0"

    defaultConfig.with {
        applicationId = "com.example.hellojni"
        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 4
        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
    }
}

compileOptions.with {
    sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
}

/*
 * native build settings
 */
android.ndk {
    moduleName = "hello-jni"
    /*
     * Other ndk flags configurable here are
     * cppFlags += "-fno-rtti"
     * cppFlags += "-fno-exceptions"
     * ldLibs    = ["android", "log"]
     * stl       = "system"
     */
}
android.buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled = false
        proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.txt')
    }
}
android.productFlavors {
    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
    create("arm") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
    }
    create("arm7") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
    }
    create("arm8") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
    }
    create("x86") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
    }
    create("x86-64") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
    }
    create("mips") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
    }
    create("mips-64") {
        ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
    }
    // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
    create("all")
}
}
```

**Android.mk**

You will need an `Android.mk` file inside the `/app/src/main/jni` directory

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

# Builds a dylib out of test.cpp
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE := test
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := test.cpp
LOCAL_LDLIBS := -llog
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
```

**test.cpp**

Add some awesome C/C++ source code for your lib. These files will start in `/app/src/main/jni` and will be compiled and linked as specified in your `Android.mk`

**Example file**

```
#include <jni.h>
#include <android/log.h>

static const char *SOME_TAG = "MyAwesomeTag";

extern "C"
{

void
Java_com_something_something_1android_ClassName_some_fn(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj)
{
    __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_VERBOSE, SOME_TAG, "Hello from NDK :)");
}

} // End extern
```

Compile and run.

Comment: The `Gradle` code you have given is for the old Android Plugin. The new `Experimental plugin` has a different `Gradle` layout. Can you please update your `Gradle` code? Thanks for the answer though.

Comment: @AUnknownHacker It's not necessarily an old vs new edit. It's more or less do you want to use gradle or a makefile for your stuff. Also, API 4 will not build for some of those triples, nor with Java v1.7.

Comment: @nathansizemore I am getting this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34953368/android-ndk-integration-errorunable-to-load-class-buildtypeimpl

Comment: What if I just want to pull in **.so** files into Android Studio?  How will they get generated?

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky if you already have the libs (.so files), there is no need to generate them. Just link to them.

Comment: @nathansizemore I meant, I have C/C++ files, but I want to generate **.so** files in Android Studio.

Comment: @IgorGanapolsky Uh, read the answer to the question? It takes you step by step.

Comment: @nathansizemore where are the .so files generated? Thanks

Comment: @Alec You mean where in the APK are they stored? Not sure what you're asking.

Comment: What they're saying is that they have some C/C++ source files in their _jni_ folder. What they want to be able to do is build this project and generate .so files instead of a .APK. The answer is that you need to set up the gradle to build a library instead of an application, then unzip/extract the resulting .aar library and find the .so files inside it. This is also how you can get a "classes.jar" as well.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo That does the same thing. Whether you get an APK or AAR at the end, you still unzip and pull the dylibs out. Why would anyone generate dylibs with Android Studio, and not use them in Android Studio?

Comment: There are people that just dump raw _.c_, _.cpp_ and _.h_ files into Android Studio's "jni" folder. In those cases the dylibs won't exist until you build the project.

Comment: @DisturbedNeo Yes. That is what the jni folder is for. The line `include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)` at the end of `Android.mk` in the answer above is what does this step.

Comment: It looks like this method is obsolete. Android studio broke projects approximately 21324236 times by changing project structure, build system and file formats. I wonder when they will stop removing futures that depends on other tools. 

from what I read com.android.model.application doesn't exist anymore

Answer (score 10):

Over a year later with Android Studio 2.2 and above, you can now get all of this done for you for free just by selecting "Include C++ Support" when creating a new project.

For more information check out: https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html.

Comment: Yeah, after a long, loooong time, Android Studio finally added full working support for NDK :)

Comment: @FadedCoder What about for the older projects? Can I still select that option which is "Include C++ Support" from somewhere? Thanks