# Android NDK Integration: Error:Unable to load class BuildType$Impl

Tags: android, android-ndk, android-gradle-plugin, android-build

I am trying to integrate NDK into my project. I am using Gradle wrapper 2.9 and classpath:`gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha3`.

Project level gradle:

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.6.0-alpha6'
      }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

App level gradle:

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'

model {
    android {
        compileSdkVersion = 23
        buildToolsVersion = "23.0.2"

        defaultConfig.with {
            applicationId = "com.ms.knowursensor.android"
            minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 11
            targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
        }
    }

    compileOptions.with {
        sourceCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility=JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    }

    android.ndk {
        moduleName = "sensorgraph"
    }
    android.buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled = false
            proguardFiles  += file('proguard-rules.txt')
        }
    }
    android.productFlavors {
        create("arm") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi"
        }
        create("arm7") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "armeabi-v7a"
        }
        create("arm8") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "arm64-v8a"
        }
        create("x86") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86"
        }
        create("x86-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "x86_64"
        }
        create("mips") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips"
        }
        create("mips-64") {
            ndk.abiFilters += "mips64"
        }
        create("all")
    }

     dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:design:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.1.1'
        compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.1.1'
    }
}
```

On building app, i receive this error:

> Error:Unable to load class
>   'com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType$Impl'. Possible causes for
>   this unexpected error include:
>
> - Gradle's dependency cache may be
>     corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.) Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires
>     network)
> - The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may
>     be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem. Stop Gradle build processes (requires
>     restart)
> - Your project may be using a third-party plugin
>     which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the
>     version of Gradle requested by the project.
>
> In the case of
>   corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then
>   killing all Java processes.

After modifying description of proguard and product flavor i am receiving this error:

```
Error:A problem occurred configuring project ':app'.
> The following model rules could not be applied due to unbound inputs and/or subjects:
    compileOptions.with { ... } @ app\build.gradle line 15, column 5
      subject:
        - compileOptions.with Object [*]
    dependencies { ... } @ app\build.gradle line 68, column 6
      subject:
        - dependencies Object [*]
  [*] - indicates that a model item could not be found for the path or type.
```

Comment: Change your proguard line to proguardFiles.add(file('proguard-rules. txt')) and temporarily comment all lines in android.productFlavors except create("all").

Comment: @Milanix I have tried that.. Now i am getting new error in line `compileOptions.with`. I have updated question

Comment: compileOptions.with{} should be inside android{}

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I had exactly the same problem, and the solution was putting 'dependencies' outside the model {}.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this will solve your problem but it may have created complications that led up to it.

Try:
proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")

Instead of the += operators. Support around the list aggregation methods has been chunky and I've found the .add() method is the one best supported.

Comment: worked for me. question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110912/unable-to-load-class-com-android-build-gradle-managed-buildtype-impl

Answer (score 0):

Try killing the daemon and rerunning the build

`gradle --stop && gradle clean build`

Comment: Its showing error: 'gradle' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.

Comment: If you are using mac you should do ./gradlew --stop && ./gradlew clean build. I was running into same issue as you today, I had some issues with my gradle file, which i have fixed now. I am using 0.6.0-alpha6, though android studio complains that alpha7 is available while with mavencentral and jcenter doesn't have aplha7.

Comment: Can you post your gradle file?

Comment: @Milanix i have posted gradle.