# Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType_Impl

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to do basic ndk implementation using android studio. Now i am  failed to sync gradle i think that some configurations are missed from  buid.gradle

**I getting this error**

Error:Unable to load class 'com.android.build.gradle.managed.BuildType_Impl'.
Possible causes for this unexpected error include:

- Gradle's dependency cache may be corrupt (this sometimes occurs after a network connection timeout.)
  Re-download dependencies and sync project (requires network)
- The state of a Gradle build process (daemon) may be corrupt. Stopping all Gradle daemons may solve this problem.
  Stop Gradle build processes (requires restart)
- Your project may be using a third-party plugin which is not compatible with the other plugins in the project or the version of Gradle requested by the project.

In the case of corrupt Gradle processes, you can also try closing the IDE and then killing all Java processes.

**My buid.gradle (app)**

```
 apply plugin: 'com.android.model.application'
    model
            {
                android {
                    compileSdkVersion = 23
                    buildToolsVersion = "23.0.1"

                    defaultConfig.with {
                        applicationId = "com.example.app"
                        minSdkVersion.apiLevel = 9
                        targetSdkVersion.apiLevel = 23
                        versionCode = 1
                        versionName = "1.0"
                    }

                }
                android.buildTypes {
                    release {
                        minifyEnabled = false
                        proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
                    }
                }

                    packagingOptions {
                        exclude 'META-INF/DEPENDENCIES'
                        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE'
                        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE'
                        exclude 'META-INF/LICENSE.txt'
                        exclude 'META-INF/NOTICE.txt'

                    }

                android.ndk {
                    moduleName = "jniSample"
                }

                android.productFlavors {
                    // for detailed abiFilter descriptions, refer to "Supported ABIs" @
                    // https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/abis.html#sa
                    create("arm") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi")
                    }
                    create("arm7") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("armeabi-v7a")
                    }
                    create("arm8") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("arm64-v8a")
                    }
                    create("x86") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("x86")
                    }
                    create("x86-64") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("x86_64")
                    }
                    create("mips") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("mips")
                    }
                    create("mips-64") {
                        ndk.abiFilters.add("mips64")
                    }
                    // To include all cpu architectures, leaves abiFilters empty
                    create("all")
                }

                dependencies {
                    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
                    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
                    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
                    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:8.4.0'

                    compile files('libs/httpclient-4.1.3.jar')
                    compile files('libs/httpcore-4.1.4.jar')
                }

            }
```

**My build.gradle (project)**

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle-experimental:0.4.0'
        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

**gradle.wrapper.properties**

```
distributionBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
distributionPath=wrapper/dists
zipStoreBase=GRADLE_USER_HOME
zipStorePath=wrapper/dists
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-2.8-all.zip
```

Comment: i just created for example

Comment: 2.8 doesn't even work with the new Android Studio build tools.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

My problems are solved the solution was putting 'dependencies' outside the model {}

and proGuard Rule changed into

```
proguardFiles.add(file("proguard-rules.txt"))
```

instead of

```
proguardFiles += file('proguard-rules.txt')
```